# Vuforia: Manipulate Current Image Before Showing it in GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, vuforia

I would like to do a **vuforia** **android** application **including** some **image processing** operations. 
I can do what I want by showing processed current image in **ImageView**. But it is too slow. I have tried to resize current image but it is not good like showing image in **GLSurfaceView**. 
So, I thought that if I do manipulation on current image then show it in **GLSurfaceView**, it will be faster.
I wonder that if it is possible. If so, how can I do this? Could someone help me about this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: by "manipulation on current image" you mean processing the presented video background (The camera input)?

Comment: yes. Actually, my purpose is showing current images fluently like a live video. I can retrieve current image from Vuforia and show it on ImageView. Even though I do not any process at the images, it is not fast enough.

Comment: Your purpose is still not clear - in all Vuforia basic samples, the live stream video is presented fluently like a video... so what are you missing? The ability to run some image processing on it?

Comment: I saw that **Vuforia** passes current images with **state** object into GL buffer as _Video Background_ in **native** part. I want to manipulate current image in the **state** object before sending to GL buffer.

Comment: Did you look at the 'Background Texture Access' example?